# Invisible levels in factors? How do you drop them?

Tags: r, methods, statistics

I am currently reducing the number of levels in my factors and have run into this problem where my factors should only be reading 1 level but it outputs a new set of variables that should have been deleted. For example:

```
x$Industry
[1] Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance Finance
[13] Finance Finance Finance Finance
3 Levels: Finance ... Please indicate the industry you work in (e.g. technology, healthcare etc):

summary(x$Industry)
Finance 
                                                                         16 
                                                   {"ImportId":"QID8_TEXT"} 
                                                                          0 
Please indicate the industry you work in (e.g. technology, healthcare etc): 
                                                                          0
```

However, it should only be showing Finance = 16. Moreover, when I view the spreadsheet in R, the other rows don't exist, or at least I can't view them on the spreadsheet itself... (ex: {"ImportId":"QID8_TEXT"} does not appear)

Comment: Deleting entries does not change levels of factors.  You can simply factor again `x$Industry <- factor(x$Industry)` or drop levels `x$Industry <- droplevels(x$Industry)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop "unused" levels in the dataframe with

```
x$Industry <- droplevels(x$Industry)
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Do you know why levels exist under my factor even though I can't view them using the spreadsheet?

Comment: What is the source of your data? How did you import them? R may create factor levels when you import data depending on the type of observations. When you create subsets which exclude observations with certain factor levels, you don't delete the different factor levels themselves. With      `droplevels` you get rid of the "empty" factor levels.